# Display PHP data in Jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page where I display few images with radio buttons. On start two images are pre selected and I merge those and show the combinations. But user can choose a different image and click on MergeImages button, which should display the combination of two images selected.

I am doing this in one php file, where I pass the selected contents via POST to the same file through AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'CreateImage.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {imagename : newImageName},
          success: function(data) {
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
          }
    });
```

I am getting a success and now I would like to display the data so that I can see the newly created images. How do I do this?

Comment: return whatever you need in `CreateImage.php` and work with that in the `success` method.

Comment: Can I display only some part of return data here? for example only two lists which contains images and nothing else.

Comment: you can do whatever you want, just make sure you are returning it from your PHP file

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to send with the ajax call the "dataType: 'image'," so the ajax call knows what to do with the returning data -- other options that I've used are dataType:'json' or 'text' or 'html', etc.
http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

actually it won't take anything but a string, so send back the image src to display. (I was thinking you wanted to return the actual image itself).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running AJAX, which uses HTTP protocol for communication, HTTP relies on `MIME type`.  Identify the callback by using 'image' as `dataType`.

```
dataType:'image',
```

Comment: I am already creating the html inside the PHP code using echo.. so The data in success functions returns the whole code which I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the data in a DIV, you can do this:

html:

```
<div id="myemptydiv"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#myemptydiv").append(data);
```

php (if you are in the same file, you have to clear the buffer 1st but you should use another php file for ajax requests instead):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['imagename'])){
while(@ob_end_clean());
//do stuff here
echo $data;
exit;
}
?>
```